# Query to sort through highscores windows phone c#

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I am having trouble with my query to display in my observable collection. I have never used linq before and I'm not sure what to do. I looked a tutorial through Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx but it not provide even close what I'm trying to do. All I need help with is writing the code to search through the database ToDoItem and display highest integer value first and then go in descending order. Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{ 
   var toDoItemsInDB = from ToDoItem todo in toDoDB.ToDoItems
                       select todo;

   ToDoItems = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>(toDoItemsInDB);

   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: The highest integer value of what? Show us the structure of `ToDoItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Just order the collection on the integer value you want to order by. Assume `Score` is this in the following example:

```
ToDoItems.OrderBy(h => h.Score);
```

Comment: What would .Score be?

Comment: I do not know what your data structure is for `ToDoItem`. Score would be the integer value you are trying to order.

Comment: I am trying to order the column. I changed your code above not to clog the page up and added a decent amount of my code.

Answer (score 0):

To order a collection in descending order...

```
var todoItems = new List<int>();
todoItems.Add(1);
todoItems.Add(2);
todoItems.Add(3);
todoItems.Add(5);

var toDoItemsInDB = todoItems.OrderByDescending(t => t);
```

or, if it has an object and property...

```
var todoItems = new List<ToDo>();
todoItems.Add(ToDo1);
todoItems.Add(ToDo2);
todoItems.Add(ToDo3);
todoItems.Add(ToDo5);

var toDoItemsInDB = todoItems.OrderByDescending(t => t.HighScores);
```